# Flask uWSGI application structure and python3 imports

Tags: python-3.x, flask, uwsgi, flask-restful

I have a basic flask-restful application with a structure that looks like this as recommended on the flask website.

```
/application
    /application
        /config.py
        /__init__.py
    /wsgi.ini
```

Slightly irrelevant, but `config.py` is generated by our CD server.

`wsgi.ini` looks likes this

```
[uwsgi]
module = application:app

master = true
processes =5

socket = /tmp/application.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

and `__init__.py` looks something like this

```
import config

from flask import Flask, request, g
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, abort


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Now when I try to startup the application using `uwsgi --ini wsgi.ini` I get this error:

```
File "./application/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import config
```

Originally `__init__.py` was called `main.py` and I executed that to debug, which is why the import is now wrong. I'm guess I will need to change the import to be `from .config import *`

My question is two fold:

1. Could I have avoided the import problem completely. ie is there a way in python3 to import sibling modules that will work for both approaches
2. is my wsgi.ini in the correct place, or should it be in the inner application directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.x dropped support for infra-package relative imports. You need to use an absolute import:

```
from application import config
```

or the [new spelling of relative imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision):

```
from . import config
```

If you need to also support legacy versions of Python you can enable this behavior with:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it does not really address the question. This method of import will work if my wsgi.ini is outside the inner application folder, which I am not sure is the correct place. And is there a way to do imports that will work regardless of whether wsgi is inside our outside the inner application folder?

Comment: The location of `wsgi.ini` is irrelevant. How do you run uWSGI? You may need to set `chdir` and/or `pythonpath` in `wsgi.ini`.